# Split Text and number from the cell in a column

Tags: sql

Hi Have column which as cell contained text and numbers and i want only numbers or seperate column of text and numbers.

Below is my current result

```
ID
Inboundshipment-49862
```

Expecting.

```
IB                ID
Inboudshipment   49862
```

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for MS SQL Server. If '-' is the delimiter character, then you can use the SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX functions.

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(ID, 1, CHARINDEX('-', ID) - 1) AS IB, 
SUBSTRING(ID, CHARINDEX('-', ID) + 1, LEN(ID)) AS IDnum
FROM 
TABLENAME
```